# Issue with do/while looping

Tags: java

I was trying to make a simple calculator but I'm kind of stuck. I have the majority of the programming there, but I don't understand why my do/while loop isn't working properly. I would like for the user to input 0 for exit, or 1~4 for the respective calculation.

However, despite my efforts I can't seem to get this working entirely. The problem is that instead of looping until the user inputs something desired, it just terminates entirely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   //variable declare
double number1,number2,answer=0;
int choice;
//scanner to get input from user
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
//ask user to input number
System.out.println("Welcome user \n---------------------------------");
System.out.println("Enter the first number");
number1 = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the second number");
number2 = sc.nextDouble();
//ask user to enter the choice
System.out.println("What would you like to do? \n1)Addtion\n2)Subtraction\n3)Multiplication\n4)Division\n0)Exit");
choice = sc.nextInt();
//condition to exit the do while loop
if(choice == 0){
break;
}
//switch condition to loop the choice
switch(choice){
case 1 : answer = calcSum(number1,number2);break;
case 2 : answer = calcSub(number1,number2);break;
case 3 : answer = calcMult(number1,number2);break;
case 4 : answer = calcDiv(number1,number2);break;
default : System.out.println("What would you like to do? \n1)Addtion\n2)Subtraction\n3)Multiplication\n4)Division\n0)Exit");break;
}
//print th result after every iteration
displayResult(answer);
}while(choice>0&&choice<5);
   }
   //calculate sum
   static double calcSum(double a, double b){
   return a+b;
   }
   //subtraction
   static double calcSub(double a, double b){
   return a-b;
   }
   static double calcMult(double a, double b){
   return a*b;
   }
   //division
   static double calcDiv(double a, double b){
   return a/b;
   }
   //print result
   static void displayResult(double result){
   System.out.println("Result is "+result);
   }

}
```

I would like for the program to validate that the user inputs something desired such as 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. I'm sorry for the difficulty, I've been learning methods and I'm getting pretty confused.

Comment: Indenting your code readably will increase the chance of people trying to read it.

Comment: One suggestion -- move the collection of the "what to do" to a method, and have it return only upon a valid entry. As it stands, if you enter "8" on the what to do, it will print the question via the `default` in the case, but then attempt to display the result.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried pasting the code and it went all wonky and didn't save indentation properly. 

Thank you Kevin, I will try your suggestion. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, assuming the problem is that when one enters, e.g., "8" for the value, the program terminates, the issue is in the test.

So, the `default` in the `switch` will display the message (and then it will output garbage for the answer), but the check is `(choice > 0 && choice < 5);` which will fail if one enters "8".

Easy solution is to do change the default to put a value in the range.